# Why is mypy giving me an error in this pyqt code?

Tags: pyqt, mypy

In a class inherited from QTableView I have this function:

```
def edit(
        self,
        index: QModelIndex,
        trigger: QAbstractItemView.EditTrigger,
        event: Optional[QEvent],
    ) -> bool:
    [...]
```

mypy reports this an error, saying:

```
error: Signature of "edit" incompatible with supertype "QAbstractItemView"  [override]
note:      Superclass:
note:          @overload
note:          def edit(self, index: QModelIndex) -> None
note:          @overload
note:          def edit(self, index: QModelIndex, trigger: EditTrigger, event: QEvent | None) -> bool
note:      Subclass:
note:          def edit(self, index: QModelIndex, trigger: EditTrigger, event: QEvent | None) -> bool
```

It looks to me as if my subclass exactly matches the second @overload definition. Why is mypy flagging this?

Comment: Overload means "supports all of the signatures", while you implement only one of those. It's unsafe: your parent class' method may be called with one argument, and your method can't, so this violates LSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @STerliakov who pointed me in the right direction. For anyone else finding this question the fix I used is below. Note that the ellipses ("...") are literally three dots rather than a placeholder for some unspecified code.

```
    from typing import overload

    @overload
    def edit(self, index: QModelIndex) -> None:
        ...

    @overload
    def edit(
        self,
        index: QModelIndex,
        trigger: QAbstractItemView.EditTrigger,
        event: Optional[QEvent]
    ) -> bool:
        ...

    def edit(self, index, trigger, event):

    [Function implementation code goes here]
```